# vector of type/class for typecasting null pointer

Tags: c++, casting, vector

I have program that currently use typecast for a null-pointer vector according to the following:

(Note the code is "principal", I have stripped most unecessary content.

```
for (i=0;i<NObjects;i++)
{
    switch (ObjectTypes[i])
    {
    case 1:
        ((File_GUI*) (NullVector[i]))->function();
        break;

    case 2:
        ((Point_GUI*) (NullVector[i]))->function();
        break;

    case 3....etc
    }
}
```

Is there any way to replace to large amount of case 1, case 2 etc with a simple array that is used for the typecasting? Hence the code would look something like this (Where of course the TypeCastVector must be created earlier and containt the datatypes for each index i:

```
for (i=0;i<NObjects;i++)
{
    ((typeCastVector[i]*) (NullVector[i]))->function();
 }
```

If possible, this would save me tons of lines of codes.

Comment: Probably a major redesign is called for that avoids a vector of null pointers. Why not have a vector of base-class pointers and invoke a virtual function call?

Comment: What useful operations can you perform on null pointers? At best `->` is going to seg-fault.

Comment: You can't call functions on null pointers, so what does this really do, and what is the contents of that vector? and why does the vector not contain pointers to a base class that is having a virtual function function() ? and why are you using c-style casts instead of c++ casts? and why are you using magic numbers instead of enums?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kerrek SB, a redesign is probably wanted so as to use a virtual function call and a base class for this purpose. If for some reason you really don't want to give File_GUI, Point_GUI, etc a base class you could do this...

```
struct BaseStorer
{
    virtual void CallFunction() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct TypeStorer : public BaseStorer
{
    TypeStorer(T* _obj) : obj(_obj) {}
    virtual void CallFunction() { obj->function(); }

    T* obj;
};
```

Store an array of BaseStorer* which are `new TypeStorer<File_GUI>(new File_GUI(...))`. Your loop would look like...

```
for (i=0;i<NObjects;i++)
{
    baseStorerVector[i]->CallFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same opinion as mentioned in comments. Presently your `ObjectTypes[]` seems to be an array (or `vector` of `int`s). You may want to change it to an array of pointers (handles) of a common base `class`. For example,

```
GUI *ObjectTypes[NObjects];
```

Where `class` hierarchy is like,

```
class GUI {  // abstract base class
public:
  virtual void function () = 0; // make it an abstract method
};

class File_GUI : public GUI {
  void function () { ... }
};
...
```

Now you can replace your call in a single line as,

```
for (i=0;i<NObjects;i++)
{
    ObjectTypes[i]->function();
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Apparently I have taken a bad direction and must do some studies and then change direction. Anyway thanks for taking the time. /Stefan